# Different results of SPSS and Python KS-test to assess normality

Tags: python, scipy, spss, scipy.stats, kolmogorov-smirnov

Suppose that I have a series of data:

> age;height
> 8;120
> 8;123
> 8;130
> 8;125
> 10;160
> 9;158
> 8;120
> 7;126
> 6;98
> 5;97
> 7;115
> 7;120
> 7;118
> 8;117
> 6;97
> 6;99
> 9;123
> 10;157
> 10;155
> 9;155
> 9;153
> 5;96
> 7;115
> 6;94
> 6;94
> 5;87
> 8;117
> 6;96
> 5;97
> 6;91
> 6;88
> 9;149
> 6;94
> 8;117
> 10;156
> 10;160
> 6;90
> 6;90
> 7;116
> 5;89
> 6;90
> 7;118
> 10;162

And I would like to assess the normality using Kolmogorov-Smirnov using both SPSS and Python. SPSS yielded a result of:

| variables | statistics | sig |
| --- | --- | --- |
| age | 0.190 | 0.000 |
| height | 0.173 | 0.002 |

I tried to compare using Python with this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import kstest
from scipy.stats import norm
data = pd.DataFrame([[8, 120], [8, 123], [8, 130], [8, 125], [10, 160], [9, 158], [8, 120], [7, 126], [6, 98], [5, 97], [7, 115], [7, 120], [7, 118], [8, 117], [6, 97], [6, 99], [9, 123], [10, 157], [10, 155], [9, 155], [9, 153], [5, 96], [7, 115], [6, 94], [6, 94], [5, 87], [8, 117], [6, 96], [5, 97], [6, 91], [6, 88], [9, 149], [6, 94], [8, 117], [10, 156], [10, 160], [6, 90], [6, 90], [7, 116], [5, 89], [6, 90], [7, 118], [10, 162]], columns=['age', 'weight'])
x = np.log(data.age)
n = norm(loc=0,scale=1)
kstest(x, n.cdf)
```

which gives:

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.9462396895483368, pvalue=5.139087762288979e-55)
```

Even if I don't log-transform the data, the result is still different:

```py
kstest(data.age, n.cdf)
```

which gives:

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.9999997133484281, pvalue=9.27397852188504e-282)
```

Answer (score 1):

The SciPy calculation is correct given your input: the KS-test statistic is the maximum difference between the empirical CDF and the provided CDF evaluated at the data.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

dist = stats.norm(loc=0, scale=1)

data = np.asarray([[8, 120], [8, 123], [8, 130], [8, 125], [10, 160], [9, 158], [8, 120], [7, 126], [6, 98], [5, 97], [7, 115], [7, 120], [7, 118], [8, 117], [6, 97], [6, 99], [9, 123], [10, 157], [10, 155], [9, 155], [9, 153], [5, 96], [7, 115], [6, 94], [6, 94], [5, 87], [8, 117], [6, 96], [5, 97], [6, 91], [6, 88], [9, 149], [6, 94], [8, 117], [10, 156], [10, 160], [6, 90], [6, 90], [7, 116], [5, 89], [6, 90], [7, 118], [10, 162]])
logage = np.log(data[:, 0])

x = np.sort(logage)
cdfvals = dist.cdf(x)
n = len(cdfvals)
dminus = (cdfvals - np.arange(0.0, n)/n)
dminus.max() # 0.9462396895483368
```

The SPSS code is not provided, so I cannot assess the reason for the discrepancy. Perhaps in SPSS you are not testing the null hypothesis that the data follows the *standard* normal distribution, which is clearly not the case. Instead, perhaps it is performing [Lilliefors' test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test), which uses the KS-statistic to perform a test of the null hypothesis that the data follows *a* normal distribution in which the parameters `loc` and `scale` are treated as unknown.

```py
res = stats.goodness_of_fit(stats.norm, logage, statistic='ks')
res.statistic  # 0.1821555634826541
res.pvalue  # 0.001
# p-value computed using Monte Carlo simulation, so results may vary.
```

If you want to perform such a test, there are many more powerful options available. Consider the [Shapiro-Wilk test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test).